# How to get parent's ID of files in Shared with me folder in Google Drive using JavaScript

Tags: fetch, drive

I was trying to fetch files in *Shared with me* folder and I fetched file name, type, size.
But I need parent's ID as well.

```
gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'q': `sharedWithMe=true`,
        'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name, thumbnailLink, mimeType, size, parents)",
    orderBy: 'name'
})
```

This is the code to query and fetch files in *Shared with me* folder.
But the parents value is empty.

I want to get parent's ID of files in *Shared with me* folder.
Thank you.